# Enterprise library 4 dataconfiguration tag

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5, enterprise-library

I am using Enterprise library for my data access.
When I am running the application, at the CreateDatabase() statement I am getting this exception:

> Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildFailedException
>   was unhandled by user code 
>   Message="The current build operation
>   (build key Build
>   Key[Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database,
>   null]) failed: 
>            The value can not be null or an empty string. 
>            (Strategy type Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ObjectBuilder.ConfiguredObjectStrategy,
>   index 2)" 
>   Source="Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2"

Now, I googled a bit and I found that I have to place

```
<dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="LocalSqlServer"/>
```

but I don't know where. Is it the right solution?

Also, at the time of installing enterprise library I didn't see any connection string statement? So, I wonder how it will take the connection string from web.config file.

In the connection string section of my web.config file I have:

```
<remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
 <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=MSTR;Initial Catalog=USERDb;Integrated Security=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you need to add the `dataConfiguration` section to the web.config.

First you need to add dataConfiguration to the list of ConfigurationSections in your web.config:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
</configSections>
```

Then you need to add your connection strings to the web.config (you've already done this):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=MSTR;Initial Catalog=USERDb;Integrated Security=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>      
</connectionStrings>
```

Then you need to add the actual dataConfiguration section to the web.config:

```
<dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="LocalSqlServer"/>
```

You can also use the Enterprise Library Configuration Tool to do this for you as well.